# operator new field value has wrong offset in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

using gcc/g++ 4.6.1  Is this a compiler bug or a language feature?  Though the compiler didn't yell at me so I guess it is a least a compiler shortcoming.

I have a parent class with operator `new` overloaded:

```
class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
}

class A{
public:
  void* operator new(size_t enfacia_size, uint count){
      size_t total_size 
      = enfacia_size
      + item::size() * count; // the 'tail'
      ;
      this_type *new_pt = (this_type *)malloc(total_size);
      new_pt->count = count;
      return new_pt;
  }
  uint count;
}

class B : public C, public A{
public:
    int i;
};
```

The object itself is variable length, so it needs to know how long it is.  Hence there is a `count` field. In this call the count is found at offset 0:

```
...
new A *pt = new(10) A;  // offset_of(A,count)==0
new B *pt = new(10) B;  // offset_of(B,count)==4
```

Here is the problem, inside of operator `new`, the value for `count` is always written at offset 0, whether it was called from the parent or from the child. So, when used in inheritance the program crashes .. Is there an issue with static methods and inheritance?   What is going on with this?

Comment: What is `this_type`? Transcription error?

Comment: A base class of variable length? Don't think so.

Comment: Please post *actual* code that *actually* demonstrates the problem, not pseudo-code that sorta-kinda describes it. Nothing shows your intent more clearly than a 20-line program that we can copy, paste, and compile. See http://sscce.org for information about why this is important.

Comment: excuse me, when simplifying I took out the typedef for 'this_type' it is what you would think. The original code was heavily templated.

[quote]
    class A{
      typedef A this_type;
      ..
    };
  
    class B{
      typedef B this_type;
      ...
    }
[/quote]
etc. each class has it

Answer (score 3):

The solution you propose invokes Undefined Behavior by accessing members of a non-POD class outside of the lifetime of that class.

Reading from §3.8 of C++2003,

> The lifetime of an object of type T begins
>   when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
> - if T is a class type with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), the constructor call has completed.

Since your `B` object has a non-trivial constructor, the lifetime begins after `B`'s constructor  has completed. `A`'s constructor runs before `B`'s constructor completes, thus before the lifetime of `B`.

> Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated … any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be … located
>   may be used but only in limited ways. …
>   If the object [*satisfies certain conditions, which yours does*], the program has
>   undefined behavior if:
>
> - the pointer is used to access a non-static data member or call a non-static member function of the object,
>     or
> - the pointer is implicitly converted (4.10) to a pointer to a base class type, or
> - the pointer is used as the operand of a static_cast (5.2.9) (except when the conversion is to
>     void*, or to void* and subsequently to char*, or unsigned char*).
> - the pointer is used as the operand of a dynamic_cast (5.2.7).

So, any solution that you propose that violates one of those four conditions invokes Undefined Behavior. Specificially, the code in your question uses the pointer as an operand of a `static_cast`, and uses it to access a non-static data member.

---

Having said all that, here is a program which, while not defined by the C++ standard, might still be valid for your particular compiler. That is, this isn't a C++ program, but it might be MSVC++ program or a G++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};

template <class this_type>
class A {
public:
  void* operator new(size_t enfacia_size, unsigned int count){
      size_t total_size
      = enfacia_size
      + 42 * count; // the 'tail'
      ;
      this_type *new_pt = (this_type *)malloc(total_size);
      new_pt->count = count;
      return new_pt;
  }
  unsigned int count;
};

class B : public C, public A<B>{
public:
    int i;
};

int main () {
  B *b = new(10) B;
  std::cout << b->count << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah Rob, I think this is an incorrect answer.  The offsets depend on the type not the instance. The object (instance) comes into being when new is finished, yes of course, but the class definition already exists before new is called.  In fact the size is part of the type, and that is one of the parameters to new.  I think this is a compiler bug, the inherited new operator thinks it is of the wrong type.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. Perhaps I made unwarranted assumptions about the code fragments you posted. But before we can judge that, we'll need to both examine the same complete program. Please create the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates the bug and paste it into your question.

Comment: Hi Rob, that is posted below.  The one with the #includes in it and the debugger output.  There seems to be a lot of confusion between type and instance especially in the nether regions of 'operator new' so little wonder this issue came up in the first place.

Comment: In that case, I stand by my analysis. The compiler is behaving perfectly correctly, both in the sense "you have invoked undefined behavior, anything can happen", and in the sense "this is exactly how the compiler author would expect it to behave." You have a `void*` that points to memory that will eventually hold an object of type `B`. You cast that pointer to type `A*`. You dereference that `A*`. You have to expect that to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot possibly work. `operator new` does not get to know the type of object being allocated. Only the size. There might be no object at all since you can call the operator directly.

Defining `this_type` in each derived class differently (I guess you have missed this part in the presentation) will not affect the meaning of it in the base class methods.

Comment: Actually Rob correctly added the template for 'this_type' I apologize to everyone for having cut a bit too much out to make the example.  His solution also works, and I very much appreciate his comments about the official lifetime of an object.  

..If I can figure out how to put code in one of these comments (it is ignoring the 4 spaces thing) I could show you the source and memory images from gdb that correspond.

BTW because of the nonstandard nature of writing the count to the field I added the count redundantly to the constructor call.  So you get:

B *pt = new(10) B(10); // count is 10

Comment: Yes the solution with the template can work, I was too quick.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for the offsets to be different between a base class and a derived class, especially when multiple inheritance is involved. The compiler provides invisible fixups to modify a pointer address whenever it converts from one type to another.

It has to be this way, because each pointer type must be consistent in the kind of object it points to. `A* p1 = new A` and `A* p2 = new B` must use the same offsets for p1 and p2.

Comment: Yes, but each instance still is supposed to correctly find it's fields. Otherwise inheritance would work. In this case you have an instance of a B type that when one of its methods, albeit an inherited one, accesses its count field it goes to the wrong place (for a B type method to go to).  When the fields move due to inheritance, the children's references move with them.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles fine:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};

class A{
public:
  typedef A this_type;

  void* operator new(size_t enfacia_size, uint count){
      size_t total_size 
    = enfacia_size
    + sizeof(int) * count; // the 'tail'
    ;
      this_type *new_pt = (this_type *)malloc(total_size);
      new_pt->count = count;
      return new_pt;
  };
  uint count;
};

class B : public C, public A{
public:
    int i;
};

int main(){
  B *b_pt = new(5) B;  
  uint j=0;
  j++;
};
```

Here is the "problem" shown in gdb:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484e1: file try_offsets.ex.cc, line 32.
(gdb) r
Starting program try_offsets 
Breakpoint 1, main () at try_offsets.cc:32
(gdb) n
(gdb) p &(b_pt->count)
$1 = (uint *) 0x804a00c
(gdb) x/10 b_pt
0x804a008:  5   0   0   0
0x804a018:  0   0   0   0
0x804a028:  0   135129
(gdb) p b_pt
$2 = (B *) 0x804a008
(gdb)
```

Notice that count is at 0x804a00c, but assigning to count wrote to 0x804a008.  Now with the variation pointed out by Rob where this type is set to the child via a template:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};

template<typename this_type>
class A{
public:

  void* operator new(size_t enfacia_size, uint count){
      size_t total_size 
    = enfacia_size
    + sizeof(int) * count; // the 'tail'
    ;
      this_type *new_pt = (this_type *)malloc(total_size);
      new_pt->count = count;
      return new_pt;
  };
  uint count;
};

class B : public C, public A<B>{
public:
    int i;
};

int main(){
  B *b_pt = new(5) B;  
  uint j=0;
  j++;
};
```

We get the correct behavior:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484e1: file try_offsets.ex.cc, line 32.
(gdb) r
Starting program
Breakpoint 1, main () at try_offsets.cc:32
(gdb) n
(gdb) p &(b_pt->count)
$1 = (uint *) 0x804a00c
(gdb) x/10 b_pt
0x804a008:  0   5   0   0
0x804a018:  0   0   0   0
0x804a028:  0   135129
(gdb)
```

It is interesting though, with this solution it will not compile when this_type is set to 'A':

```
class B : public C, public A<A>{
public:
    int i;
};
```

gives:

```
try_offsets.cc:26:31: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class this_type> class A’
try_offsets.cc:26:31: error:   expected a type, got ‘A’
```

The solution I settled on:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};


class A{
public:
  typedef A this_type;

  A(uint count):count(count){;}

  void* operator new(size_t enfacia_size, uint count){
      size_t total_size 
    = enfacia_size
    + sizeof(int) * count; // the 'tail'
    ;
      this_type *new_pt = (this_type *)malloc(total_size);
      return new_pt;
  };
  uint count;
};

class B : public C, public A{
public:
    B(uint count):A(count){;}
    int i;
};

int main(){
  B *b_pt = new(5) B(5);  
  uint j=0;
  j++;
};
```

Though this breaks an old convention.  It is normal for an allocator to write the length of an allocation just above the allocation point.  That is, for example, how delete/free knows how long a block on the heap is.  Also, as operator delete can not take arguments, this is how we get information to it.

Comment: > "_It is interesting though, with this solution it will not compile when this_type is set to 'A'_"

That's because the template argument for `A` must be a type, and `A` is not a type, it's a class template.

`A<int>` is a type and `A<B>` is a type, but `A` is not.

Comment: Notice the critical (and only) difference between the first and 2nd example: in the first, `new_pt` is of type `A*`; in the 2nd, it is of type `B*`.

Comment: Yep, Jonathan, I was only pointing out that creating a base class type would be a self-referential template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You're making some strange claims about "fields moving due to inheritance" but no such thing happens.

Try  this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

struct C
{
    int i;
};

struct A
{
    int count;

    void f()
    {
        uintptr_t pt = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this);
        uintptr_t pc = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&count);
        std::cout << "Offset of A::count within A is " << (pc - pt) << '\n';
    }
};

struct B : C, A
{
    void g()
    {
        uintptr_t pt = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this);
        uintptr_t pc = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&count);
        std::cout << "Offset of A::count within B is " << (pc - pt) << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.f();
    B b;
    b.f();
    b.g();
}
```

This produces:

```
Offset of A::count within A is 0
Offset of A::count within A is 0
Offset of A::count within B is 4
```

It doesn't matter if you call A::f on an object of type B or an object of type A,  it's still A::f and it still accesses A:count at a fixed offset.  When you call B::g *then* the function knows the A::count member is at a different offset from `this`

The same thing happens in your `operator new`, that function is a member of A and knows nothing about B. When you access `this_type::count` you are accessing `A::count`. It is irrelevant that you call it for a B, only `A::operator new` exists (the function isn't copied to produce `B::operator new` as you seem to think).

The template version works because then the type `this_type` refers to B not A, so the function accesses `B::count`

Comment: was at offset 0 from base of the object, after inheritance it is at offset 4.  Call it what you like, I call it moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes field move in multiple inheritance, here is an example showing a moving field, with the same code form as he original example.  The only significant difference being that instead of being called 'operator new' the method is called 'method'.  After the code example is the debugger output showing the field moved, and the value correctly assigned to the field even through it moved:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};


class A{
public:
  typedef A this_type;

  void* method(uint count){
    void *vp;
    vp = (void *)this;
    this_type *p;
    p = (this_type *)vp;
    p->count = count;   
  };

  uint count;
};

class B : public C, public A{
public:
    typedef B this_type;
    int i;
};

int main(){
  int j;

  A a;
  a.method(5);
  j++;

  B b;
  b.method(5);
  j++;

};
```

Debugger output:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484a1: file try_offsets_2.ex.cc, line 36.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /try_offsets_2 
Breakpoint 1, main () at try_offsets_2.ex.cc:36
(gdb) n
(gdb) 
$1 = (A *) 0xbffff758
(gdb) x /10x &a
0xbffff758: 0x00000005  0x003dbff4  0x08048500  0x003dbff4
0xbffff768: 0x00000000  0x0027d113  0x00000001  0xbffff804
0xbffff778: 0xbffff80c  0x0012eff4
(gdb) n
(gdb) x /10x &b
0xbffff74c: 0x003dc324  0x00000005  0x00296c55  0x00000005
0xbffff75c: 0x003dbff5  0x08048500  0x003dbff4  0x00000000
0xbffff76c: 0x0027d113  0x00000001
(gdb)
```

Notice the 5, which was at offset 0 in the parent is at offset 4 in the child.  Notice also that though the parent method was inherited to the child that its type was updated so that it correctly wrote to the field at offset 4.

Comment: so 'operator new' behaves differently in inheritance with respect to type in gcc than other methods and operators

Comment: _Notice the 5, which was at offset 0 in the parent is at offset 4 in the child._  Yes, because the A sub-object is at offset 4 in the B that contains it.  A::count is at offset 0 into an A, and there's an A at offset 4 into a B. There's no "moving" -- A::count is always at offset 0 inside an A object.

Comment: `this_type` does not do what you think it does. Inside `A::method`, `this_type` is always `A`. It is never, ever, `B`. Therefore `this` and `p` have the same static type: namely `A*`. All of your casting in that routine does nothing.

Comment: This guy should not be allowed near a compiler, he's completely unwilling to stop and listen or learn from other people's advice.  I wonder why he bothered signing up to SO.

Comment: Wow thanks Jonathan, really make me appreciate participating in the community.  Hope you are doing a good job over there at GNU taking people's bug reports and making them glad to be participating also.

Comment: I tried repeatedly to explain it, you're not interested in understanding the answer.

Comment: Good point Rob. I had considered this_type to not do anything until I went to take it out. I had to replace it with what (A *), but Jonathan made short work of that.

Though lets not lose the point of the post.  When we use a method other than operator new, then the inheritance works. If we are to say that assigning to the object in operator new is illegal, seems the compiler should say something rather than generating code that doesn't work.  However, the type info is available, seems new could work like other methods.

Comment: Sorry to be thick headed Jon. Perhaps you could boil it down to the essentials here,  are you saying that assignment is illegal in operator new so there should be no error and you get the wrong result?  Is that your point?  Or are you saying my code assigned to count incorrectly, so then how should it be done?

Comment: I'm saying you cast the malloc'd memory to A* in order to set A::count (so the assignment happens at a specific memory address). Then you return the malloc'd memory from operator new and the compiler casts it to B*, which is **not** the same type as A*, so when you dereference the count member through the B* you get a different memory location to the one you wrote to.  The location b_pt->count is not the right location, it's not where the B object's count member is going to live, you wrote to the wrong place.

Comment: Try adding this before you return from operator new:  `B* bp = (B*)(void*)new_pt; assert(bp->count == new_pt->count);`  If you were writing to the right location, that would work, but new_pt points to the wrong place for a B, so the assertion fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int uint;

class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};

class A{
public:
  uint count;
};

class B : public C, public A{
public:
    int i;
};

template<typename T>
struct A_allocation_helper : T
{
  void* operator new(size_t enfacia_size, uint count){
    size_t total_size
      = enfacia_size
      + sizeof(int) * count; // the 'tail'
      ;
    T *new_pt = (T *)malloc(total_size);
    new_pt->count = count;
    return new_pt;
  };

};


int main(){
  B *b_pt = new(5) A_allocation_helper<B>;
  return b_pt->count;
};
```

Now the code that does the memory allocation knows the correct type, instead of it being done by a type that only knows about the base.

Comment: That is cool. No self-referential templates to get the base class. The type cast is clean. I still have the question as to why the other code works that casts a void *, though inside of method().  I will post it below.

Answer (score 0):

This code also has a void pointer in a method cast to the local type:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned int uint;

class C{ // just here to be faithful to the original code
  int y;
};


class A{
public:
  typedef A this_type;

  void* method(uint count){
    void *vp;
    vp = (void *)this;
    this_type *p;
    p = (this_type *)vp;
    p->count = count;   
  };

  uint count;
};

class B : public C, public A{
public:
    typedef B this_type;
    int i;
};

int main(){
  int j;

  A a;
  a.method(5);
  j++;

  B b;
  b.method(5);
  j++;

};
```

And it works as expected:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484a1: file try_offsets_2.ex.cc, line 36.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /try_offsets_2 
Breakpoint 1, main () at try_offsets_2.ex.cc:36
(gdb) n
(gdb) 
$1 = (A *) 0xbffff758
(gdb) x /10x &a
0xbffff758:    0x00000005    0x003dbff4    0x08048500    0x003dbff4
0xbffff768:    0x00000000    0x0027d113    0x00000001    0xbffff804
0xbffff778:    0xbffff80c    0x0012eff4
(gdb) n
(gdb) x /10x &b
0xbffff74c:    0x003dc324    0x00000005    0x00296c55    0x00000005
0xbffff75c:    0x003dbff5    0x08048500    0x003dbff4    0x00000000
0xbffff76c:    0x0027d113    0x00000001
(gdb)
```

You can see count for the child was set.  Yes, I know how this works, and yes of course this is the expected result. The reason being, the 'this' pointer is correctly set when method() is called.

The question, the original question here, is that operator new does not produce the expect result for the child, instead acting like the parent type.  Yet, operator new with assignment in it is inherited without any noise from the compiler.

I think, the real answer to all of this is that operator new differs from other methods in that it is not passed a phantom first operand of a this pointer.  And how could it as n.m. pointed out above, as the object does not exist yet.  Though the type definition already exist, the means by which the compiler communicates type to child methods in multiple inheritance is through the phantom first operand this pointer that has been set to point to the proper area of the object for the type the method was defined under.

If the compiler gave us a this_type in the manner of a this pointer, then operator new could access fields in the allocation it has created simply by casting the void *.  This would be very helpful in many situations.

But the bottom line question that remains to me is why the compiler does not give an error for the illegal assignment, and then  goes and generates code that yields wrong values for the child, as shown in the original code.  (and Jon, yes, I called new on the child and it assigned count as a parent, no warning, etc. that is fair to say, an unexpected outcome in the eyes of any usual programmer).

Comment: `operator new` is a static member, and static member functions **never** get passed `this`. But what you're saying above is _sort-of_ right, the reason the code above works is that the compiler knows how to adjust the `this` pointer for a base class subobject (what you keep calling a parent object, but that's a bad term, parents do not live inside their children!)  When you had a `void*` pointing to raw, untyped memory and you manually cast it to the wrong type, you defeated the compiler's type checking.

Comment: This begs the question, if the compiler can adjust for other methods, why not for operator new - though if accessing type is illegal, and I have all the checks turned on, why doesn't the compiler yell at me?

Comment: operator new is till unique among static members even as you can't pass in a this pointer.  The reason that is important is that in inheritance the this pointer carries the type information for methods because the compiler choses the this pointer that corresponds to the data section for the appropriate base the method came from - so it carries the type information.